# Pasar de String a Double evitando error Null y Malformato en Java

Tags: java

¿Cual es la manera optima de pasar un `String` a `Double`?

Teniendo en cuenta si la cadena es `null` sea equivalente a `0.0` y si no hay número a convertir también `0.0`

```
0.125   > 0.125
a3.72b  > 3,72
abcde   > 0.0
null    > 0.0
```

Tengo lo siguiente pero con bug en pasar `a3.72b` que devuelve `0.0` y me gustaría que devolviese `3.72`, no ser si con una expresi´no regular es más eficiente todo el proceso

```
  private static Double StringToDouble(String s) {
    Double d = 0.0;

   try {
        d = (s!=null) ? Double.valueOf(s) : 0.0;

   }catch (NumberFormatException e){
       System.out.println("not a number"); 
   }     
    return d;   

  }
```

Comment: El hecho de que trates de interpretar cadenas con formatos técnicamente inválidos hace que la pregunta sea un poco amplia.  Debes definir más precisamente la lógica de lo que consideras una cadena interpretable y de qué manera interpretarla. Por ejemplo, ¿como interpretarías...: `"-a56hello.world98"`?  `-56.98`, `56`, `-56`, `-5698`, `5698`, `0.0`??

Comment: "*¿Cual es la manera más optima de pasar un `String` a `Double`?*" No existe manera *más optima* de hacer algo, [óptimo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R7bbor7) es un superlativo que literalmente significa que no puede ser mejor.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster en terminos computancial si que existen optimo es quien conlleva menos esfuerzo a la CPU para otorgar el mismo resultado, si una excepcion hay más ciclos de CPU vs una expresión regular, pues es mas optimo usar la expresión regular, pero está claro depende de la implementación necesaria. Cambiare optimo por eficiente

Comment: @Webserveis no estoy discutiendo el término "*óptimo*" si no la frase "*más óptimo*". Un algoritmo puede ser "óptimo" y es lo que describes, un algoritmo no puede ser "más óptimo" porque óptimo es un superlativo: no se puede ser más óptimo, o se es óptimo o no se es.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si tu requerimiento requiere únicamente los valores numéricos, el punto decimal y el signo negativo si es que existe; como opción puedes agregar una REGEX para eliminar los caracteres no numéricos, conservando el signo negativo si es que existe:

```
 s = s.replaceAll("[^\\d.-]", "");
```

método:

```
private static Double StringToDouble(String s) {
    Double d = 0.0;
    //Elimina valores no numericos
    s = s.replaceAll("[^\\d.-]", "");
    try {
        d = (s!=null) ? Double.valueOf(s) : 0.0;

    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("not a number");
    }
    return d;

}
```

Estos son ejemplos de lo que realizaría el método:

- Valor de cadena `"0.125"`, resultado: `0.125`
- Valor de cadena `"a3.72b"`, resultado: `3.72`
- Valor de cadena `"null"`, resultado: `0.0`
- Valor de cadena `"a56hello.world98"`, resultado: `56.98`
- Valor de cadena `"-56.98"`, resultado: `-56.98`
- Valor de cadena `"-a56hello.world98"`, resultado: `-56.98`

Answer (score 2):

Lo más recomendable, en mi opinión y uso diario, es que lo dejes como `null` (nulo) cuando no es convertible y cuando siempre esperas que sea un número válido. En cambio, cuando el uso del número es requerido, lo más indicado es arrojar la excepción.

```
    private static Double StringToDouble(String s) {
       Double d = null;

       if(s!=null){
          try {
               d = Double.valueOf(s);
          }catch (NumberFormatException e){
               // ignora el error o sálvalo en la bitácora para referencia.
          }
       }
       return d;   
    }
```

Comment: Me ha gustado tu plantenamiento en dejar null a cambio de 0.0

Answer (score -2):

Acabo de encontrar varias maneras

`Double d= amountStr != null ? Double.parseDouble(amountStr) : 0;`

Dentro de una función

```
public static double parseDoubleOrNull(String str) {
    return str != null ? Double.parseDouble(str) : 0;
}
```

se usa

`double d = parseDoubleOrNull(ammountStr);`

Y para comprobar si es nulo, detectando mal formato

```
public static double parseDoubleSafely(String str) {
    double result = 0;
    try {
        result = Double.parseDouble(str);
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    }
    return result;
}
```

Extraído de esta respuesta [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6284521/3464919)

Comment: Pero esto no contesta tu propia pregunta donde quieres que pueda convertir a un numero aun cuando hay algunos caracteres erróneos.

Comment: no, pero si alguien quieren modificar a su gusto es una base